# Android notification turn on banner setting programmatically

Tags: android, android-notifications

Is there any ways for turning on the banners setting (display on top of the status bar) in application notification programmatically?

[image]

```
<pre><code>
// send notification to NotificationManager   
Notification.Builder notificationBuilder =new Notification.Builder(context);  
notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_32x32)  
.setLargeIcon(bitmap)  
.setContentTitle("title")  
.setContentText("content")  
.setContentIntent(contentIntent)  
.setAutoCancel(true)  
.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)        
.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)  
.setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE);  

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){                             
notificationBuilder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);  
}  

NotificationManager notificationManager =  
(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);  
notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());
</code></pre>
```

Comment: Still no solution? I still have the same issue even using .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH) and setting the channel to IMPORTANCE_MAX

Comment: Did u got any solution for this? @cwai ?

Answer (score 3):

Same problem. 
I solved this issue simply adding in the AndroidManifest.xml the ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

Nothing more is required (at least for me).

Comment: if above permission added then is it guarantee hands up notification comes over Activity. what if the user changed notification settings. how we can know about changes in settings.

Answer (score 1):

Usually for settings you need to get the user to permission, you can do this in your java class.

You can send the user to the settings so they can give you the permission that you want. However, it sounds to me that you are looking for heads-up notifications. If that is the case:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Heads-up

In simple words, set a priority of high in your notification manager class.

Comment: Notification manager have setted high priority already. The heads-up notifications only show when my app notification turn on banners.

So i want to know is there any method to turn on the banners setting.

Comment: Then please upload your notification manager code. Also, is it heads up notifications what you are looking for?

Comment: The heads-up notifications only show when my app notification turn on banners setting which is a setting inside my app notification setting.

Is it a setting of special devices?

Comment: Nope, heads-up notifications do not require any special settings for any android version, setting the notification priority to High or Max is a trigger of this kind of notifications. Something else might be wrong in your notification builder

Comment: Is the variable "id" unique? from: notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build()); if not, thats your problem, if you want unique notifications you have to make that notification id unique, otherwise you are just updating previous one. Also, make sure you included: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" /> in your manifest