# Permissions for Banner notification in Android

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, whatsapp

I am trying to implement an application in Android which needs to show Banner notifications, like in the image below.

[image]

It works well on most of the devices. But on some devices it doesn't show banner notification, instead it just shows as a normal notification.

It doesn't work especially in Huawei devices. Looking for the issues I was able to see that there is an options in the settings which will let you customize the notifications. And some apps will have the banner permission enabled for showing notifications.

[image]

I was able to see that some apps including WhatsApp was able to get the Banner permission enabled, directly after the app is installed. If I toggle the banner permission to enabled manually in my application, then everything works as expected.

Is there some special AndroidManifest permission needed or should I be doing something specific to have the banner notification enabled.

Comment: Did you figure out how?

Comment: got any solution>

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

Source - [Android notification turn on banner setting programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711788/android-notification-turn-on-banner-setting-programmatically)

For more info have a look on [Manifest](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission) and [Notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Heads-up) documentation.